# How to execute application code during this application installation in InstallShield 2016 Premier Edition (21-days trial)?

Tags: c#, installshield

I create now Windows installation project (ISM) of my C# WPF Prism MVVM modular application. I use for it InstallShield 2016 Premier (21-days trial). In my C# WPF application I have Properties.Settings.Default flag called IsFirstRunAfterInstallation. The type of this flag is bool. I need that this flag **must be set to true during the installation process**. After completion of the installation when the application is run first time, IsFirstRunAfterInstallation flag is checked as the following:

```
if (My_assembly_name.Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRunAfterInstallation)
{
    // do some actions here that must be done when application runs first time after its installation.
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    My_assembly_name.Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRunAfterInstallation = false;
    My_assembly_name.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

And if IsFirstRunAfterInstallation flag is *tru*e, some C# code that is needed to perform when the application runs first time will be executed (as you can see above). So I need that IsFirstRunAfterInstallation flag is set to *true* like the folowing:

```
 My_assembly_name.Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRunAfterInstallation = true;
 My_assembly_name.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

during each installation of my application on customer computer and is checked after the installation when the application runs first time. So I have the followin question: How to execute application code during the application installation using InstallShield 2016 Premier Edition (21-days trial)?

Answer (score 1):

If the you need `IsFirstRunAfterInstallation` true (by default) for every version of your application then I do not think you need to do anything with installshield.

1- Set the `IsFirstRunAfterInstallation` default value true (in application properties).

2- Change the application version number for every release (from application properties OR directly in `AssemblyInfo.cs` class).

It will be always true on application first run/launch after installation because for application every new version, a separate directory is created in %AppData%\Local\\\\ and settings are copied/saved to user.config.

For above approach do you do not need to do anything custom/additional since application maintain version specific settings it self, however there are alternatives you may use:
1- Create a separate exe (a console application) or a dll and use it as custom action. OR
2- Launch your application from installshield and Pass a commandline parameter something /IsFirstLaunch:True

The parameters passed from installshield custom action can be received in application main:

```
private static void Main()
{
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
//Process args here
}
    OR
private static void Main(string [] args)
{
//Process args here. 
}
```

Comment: Note that it's worth considering upgrade scenarios. It's possible this "first run" code may need to be run again after an upgrade, and if the installation doesn't reset it, the app will have to determine this some other way. Perhaps store the last version for which the "first run" code has been run instead of just a boolean.

Comment: I also need to set IsFirstRunAfterInstallation to true in case of redeployment (reinstall) the same application version on the same computer. Michael Urman, please help if possible ofcource.

Comment: if IsFirstRunAfterInstallation default value is set to true then on changing application version for every release (deployment) it will always be true on first launch after upgrade. but as @MichaelUrman said, you may also save the application current version to file system/txt file before setting flag to false.